# Collect GCP metrics without stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, metrics, stackdriver

I need to fetch the GCP metrics without using stackdriver api(without enabling the stackdriver api). Ex. Pub/Sub metrics -> pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/ack_message_count.

Answer (score 1):

You can interact directly with the [Stackdriver Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/) to retrieve the [metrics you're interested in](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-pubsub).

However, this requires the Stackdriver Monitoring API to be enabled since this will start the metric collection (which is needed before you can start fetching them).

Having the API enabled has the additional advantage that has support for the [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries), making metrics fetching easier.

As a partial workaround and specific for `ack_message_count`, you can use the libraries to take advantage of [the `seek` method](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/seek#request-body) available in the PubSub API to get the retained messages in any given subscription:

> Messages retained in the subscription that were published before this time are marked as acknowledged, and messages retained in the subscription that were published after this time are marked as unacknowledged. Note that this operation affects only those messages retained in the subscription

This implies that the data is constantly pulled and stored (if needed) in your own persistence layer for latter usage/aggregation.

Comment: Is there any other way to fetch the metrics without enabling the StackDriver Monitoring APIs?

Comment: That API is meant to collect and give user-access to the data. As mentioned, a potential alternative would be checking each API to determine if, manually, you can make metrics out of their available information. Although I personally find that very unreliable.

Comment: But for using these apis , I need to enable stackdriver monitoring apis , If I am understanding this right , Then is there any way to get metrics without enabling stackdriver monitoring apis .

Comment: GCP separated each product and API. So, if you want to use the PubSub API, there is no need to enable the Monitoring API. The idea is, for each resource that you want metrics (PubSub, GCE, GCF, etc.), to see if their API has data regarding any specific information you want, to transform it into metrics "manually". In my example, using the `seek` method enabled in the PubSub API might give you the acknowledged message count, which can be retrieved to make a time series separately.

Comment: can you please give a example , how to fetch/collect any information about pub/sub . a demo programme .

Comment: Interacting with the APIs to get information deeply depends on what you're trying to achieve and the API methods available. My suggestion was specifically [based on PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#receive_messages), but other APIs might require completely different approaches to "collect their metrics". At the end and as mentioned, is the least reliable way to fetch metrics. In your current scenario it might be best to enable the API.